# Saving rasters as in batch process

Tags: geotiff-tiff, export, tiles, batch, save

I've found a few questions similar but think mine is much more simple.

I would like to run: `Export -> Save As` as a batch command.

I have 1 layer that has 9595 DEM raster overlaid and I would like to save the 1 layer underneath, clipped into the extents of each DEM file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyqgis to list all rasters, find each ones extent and then `Clip raster by extent`:

```py
import os

outfolder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\out_clip' #Change
raster_to_clip = r"C:\GIS\data\Bakgrundskartor_LMV\sve_1milj_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff\sverigekartan\s1milj.tif" #Change to the layer you want to clip. Dont add this to QGIS!
rasterlayers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if isinstance(layer, qgis._core.QgsRasterLayer)] #List all raster layers added to the map

for rlyr in rasterlayers: #For each rasterlayer
  e = rlyr.extent() #Find extent
  xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin = e.xMaximum(), e.xMinimum(), e.yMaximum(), e.yMinimum()
  processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbyextent",
                 {'INPUT':raster_to_clip,
                 'PROJWIN':'{0}, {1}, {2}, {3} []'.format(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax),
                 'NODATA':None,
                 'OPTIONS':'',
                 'DATA_TYPE':0,
                 'EXTRA':'',
                  'OUTPUT':os.path.join(outfolder, os.path.basename(raster_to_clip[:-4])+'_{}.tif'.format(rlyr.name()))}
                 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks BERA, Appreciate you taking the time.

Can I use Raster and Raster?

Kindest regards, 

Chris

Comment: You want to clip a raster file using raster extents? Try again I've changed the code.

Comment: Sorry BERA, I've just seen this. Again really appreciate you taking the time.

I'll give this a wack now.